# Need advice on power supply for a device in India purchased from USA

Tags: power-supply, voltage, power, conversion

I bought an Epson Powerlite HC 2040 projector from Amazon US site. I am going to use it in India.

However, the power cable that comes with it has a tag stating (10A 125V). Since I am an ordinary user I am not sure what that means and exactly what I need in order to use the device in India.

I assume I will need a power adaptor for the plug but please advise if I will also need a power convertor (step up/step down)? On epson product sheet they say the device supports 240v. But I am little concerned and want to rule out the possibility of any damage to the device.

Here is the product data sheet : http://www.projectorcentral.com/pdf/projector_spec_8947.pdf

Thank you for all the help good people on this site may offer.

EDIT Nov 9:
Thank you for all the helpful answers.

EDIT Nov 10 [Final]:
Thank you again for the help. I followed the suggestion offered here, but instead of ditching the epson power cable, I simply used a wall plug adaptor for the cable (insanely cheap). The device is operational without problem. Apologies if this post does not belong here, but to me, the answer here is worth $1000 that I invested in the imported device. I truly appreciate your time and kind help.

Comment: We really need a generic answer for this.

Comment: On the datasheet it states: *Power Supply Voltage 100 – 240 V AC +/-10%, 50/60 Hz*. The projector uses a standard 3-pin mains input identical to the ones you will find on PCs and many other devices. So just discard the cable which comes with the projector (since  it will have a US plug) and use one that you can also use for a PC etc.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie And yet another _answer_ in the comment section.

Comment: @pipe I agree but truth is most new users just ask and don't bother searching for the nice generic answer :-(

Comment: Yes I do that, so sue me. I only write answers when non-trivial information needs to be communicated.

Comment: Thank you @Bimpelrekkie for taking the time to answer. That was insightful.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Yeah, that's difficult to avoid. With a generic answer we can at least close the questions as a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, what says on the cable has very little to do with anything. You didn't buy it for the cable.

From the manual:

> **Power Supply Voltage** 100 – 240 V AC +/-10%, 50/60

So you just need another power cable, on that fits physically in your socket.

Comment: Thank you @pipe. Does that imply I can simply use an adaptor to fit in an indian wall socket rather than discard the cable?

Comment: @vjswami Sure, but a new cable is probably cheaper.

Comment: You are probably right, but I have a wall plug adaptor easily available in neighborhood shops for less than $1, while I will have hard time looking for a compatible cable in the marketplace, which is quite some distance to reach. Even then, I think the female end of the Epson Cable has pin sockets in a "rectangle shape" but in india they are "round" :) I don't have the device handy so I will update when I get home. Thank you

Comment: @vjswami Ah, I had no idea the adapters were so cheap.

Comment: @programmer: The $1 power adaptor is very cheap and so will probably have poor contacts. If the plug loses contact or is easily pulled from the adaptor your projector will shut down without running through the required cooling procedure. The cost of replacing the lamp or other electronics inside the projector will make your saving on not purchasing the correct cable seem rather stupid.

Comment: @Transistor. Yes, your concern is very genuine. Thank you. It's not about the money alone, it's about the quality of the cable supplied with it. I live in a semi urban area and finding a decent cable of that build quality in my local market is quite a herculean job. I remember I bought one for PC years ago that tripped (busted) on the plug end. I do not question the veracity of your kind advice, but I think an adaptor serves my purpose quite well. I'll certainly buy an expensive one. I've been using an iMac21 since 2009 with an adaptor without the stated problem (I kinda glued them together :)

Comment: @Transistor The fact is I will have more problem with sudden power outage in my area rather than cable getting accidental pulled off the plug. Anyway, I appreciate.

Comment: Also, did not mean to string the topic along, but I noticed the projector shuts down in a jiffy. So I am sure it is designed that way (without needing a cooling time/procedure).

Answer (score 1):

What's written on cable is the specification of cable, the cable is designed that way.

As far as your projector is concerned it states that it can operate under 100 to 240V +-10%, 50/60Hz which is more than fine for you to run it from any wall plug.

Comment: Thank you @Mayank. I appreciate your reply. So I just use a compatible wall plug for the cable? Will that work?

Comment: yes. What i understand from the datasheet that any standard PC power supply cable will work with it. Its not a big deal, the main objective to achieve here to provide power to projector so you basically need a wire that can connect the 2 ends, and the american plug wont fit into sockets in India. Just buy a new power chord and you should be fine.

Comment: You're right. I just mustered some courage and based on the advice from good people like yourself here simply hooked the epson projector cable into an adaptor (universal plug from my mac) and connected it to wall socket and whew!! It started blinking at me :) I am going to use the cable that came with it, and just purchase a new universal plug (30Rs only). So, it's cheaper alternative than replacing the cable.

Comment: Mayank, I am accepting the answer from "pipe" as Solved as he responded sooner, nevertheless, answers from you and @Bimpelrekkie were equally helpful and appreciated.